# How do I light fire?

Tags: dnd-5e

What mechanics/objects are there in the D&D world to light fire. I'm thinking to literally light some kindling/flaming arrows etc.

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort. There are a ton of these throughout the PHB...

Comment: I'm voting to put this ticket on hold - as written, the answer would be a LONG list, and there are no criteria given. Surely you can think of *a* way to light a fire in DND - what makes that not good enough? What problem are you trying to solve with this question?

Comment: @SirTechSpec It appears from the text that the emphasis is on mechanical (non magical?) means, however, more detail would be helpful.  Good point on the list question, I made some assumptions when I responded that may not be warranted.

Answer (score 2):

#### Tinderbox is a mundane means for lighting a fire

Its in the PHB equipment list, and in the Basic Rules (BR p. 48 / PHB p. 150)
Lower end, right column.

> Tinderbox 5 sp 1 lb.
>   Torch 1 cp 1 lb.
>   Vial 1 gp —
>   Waterskin 2 sp
>   5 lb. (full)
>   Whetstone 1 cp 1 lb.
>   (BR p. 48 / PHB p. 150)
>   {snip}
>   **Tinderbox**. This small container holds flint, fire steel,and tinder
>   (usually dry cloth soaked in light oil) used to kindle a fire. Using
>   it to light a torch—or anything else with abundant, exposed fuel—takes
>   an action. Lighting any other fire takes 1 minute. (Basic Rules p. 50 / PHB p. 153)

If you already have a lit torch, that takes care of your fire arrows.

Depending upon what your party typically carries, you can keep one of these lit to light other things:

> Lamp 5 sp     1 lb.
>   Lantern, bullseye  10 gp 2 lb.
>   Lantern, hooded
>   5 gp   2 lb.
>   (BR p. 48 / PHB p. 150)

Insofar as cantrips, if reusable resources are what you are after, there are a variety but the Druid's *produce flame* is an all purpose way to light flaming arrows and start fires, and *druidcraft* has a firestarting feature to it as well.